# Wordpress Feed Creator Name Tag Full Name Instead Of First Name

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed

I am parsing a Wordpress feed in my iOS application. I don't know much about Wordpress and its customisation. The feed shows the author name as below:

```
<dc:creator>andy</dc:creator>
```

while i want it to show the full name of the author in the feed like:

```
<dc:creator>andy rubin</dc:creator>
```

Can anybody point out where i can go to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open your Wordpress dashboard and go to Users > All Users and select edit for the user for which you want the full name to appear. You will see the option "Display name publicly as". From drop down list you can choose the full name.

[image]

In the feed you might still see first name but once you parse it in your iOS project, it will show you the full name.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of ways to customize your feeds.

1 - through the use of a **WordPress pluggins** such as http://wordpress.org/plugins/feed-template-customize/

2 - **changing display settings** from the Wordpress dashboard

3 - or by **manually changing the feed templates** to meet your needs

Editing your feed templates manually is much the same as editing your theme templates but not integrated into WP theme system

The Feed templates are located in the `/wp-includes/feed-{type}.php` files and include formats for rdf, rss, rss2 and atom but it is better to do not edit directly the files from this folder.

You can follow the [Customizing Feed Templates section](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds) of the codex and peek the function you need [from this list](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/comment_author_rss) and use it within the Loop.